# Save Values recursiv using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, file, recursion, streamwriter

Current Function:

```
 private static void saveDirAndFilesV23(TreeNode currNode, StreamWriter streamWriter)
    {
        streamWriter.Write(currNode.Value);
        if (currNode.ValueType == "FILE")
        {
            streamWriter.Write(String.Format("<code><pre>{0}</pre></code>", File.ReadAllText(currNode.Value)));
        }

        foreach (TreeNode item in currNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            saveDirAndFilesV23(item, streamWriter);
        }
    }
```

Problem is the generated File is empty.. I don't know why.

Main:

```
 saveDirAndFilesV23(root, new StreamWriter("test.html"));
```

Why does it not save?

My Save Function:

```
  public static TreeNode GetFolderStructure(string path, List<string> allExt)
    {
        TreeNode result = new TreeNode(path, "DIR");

        foreach (string dirName in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            if (!(GetFolderStructure(dirName, allExt).ChildNodes.Count == 0))
                result.Append(GetFolderStructure(dirName, allExt));
        }

        foreach (string item in allExt)
        {
            foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(path, item))
            {
                result.Append(fileName, "FILE");
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The Save Function gets called right but does not write in the file.

Comment: Are you Closing/Flushing/Disposing the StreamWriter?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen no? Must I..

Comment: Yes, you must. See below. And we can't see how you fill the tree either.